# K8s nginx ingress SSL - should I use SSL also inside K8s?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, nginx-ingress

I am working on moving my applications inside K8s.

I am planning to use K8s Nginx ingress controller. In my K8s I will have several pods with own nginx (php applications).

For now I can`t understand - how I can use SSL for HTTPS?
Should I configure SSL certs/nginx config **ONLY** inside my pods or **ONLY** for nginx ingress or **BOTH** nginx ingress and pods?

All my applications is using the same SSL cert (one domain name with different subdomains).

What is correct way for that?

Comment: There is no correct answer to this. This depends on what you want. Do you trust your clusters internal network or not.

Comment: It depends. First you should take a look at your requirements. Does traffic in your cluster need to be encrypted? Do you trust the hardware and the network your cluster is running in? If for example the CNI in your cluster is already encrypting traffic between `Pods` and `Nodes`, then there could very easily be no additional benefit to configuring TLS for your Pods. If encryption is necessary you could also use a Service Mesh like Linkerd or Istio to transparently encrypt all traffic between your `Pods`.

Comment: I am trust to my cluster but my apps already are using HTTPS, and I don`t want to update app logic to find/replace code to use HTTP or disable SSL verification. So, it is better for me to use SSL both - should I use the same SSL in this case?